# Is there any permanent fix for no wifi with iwlwifi other than removing the .pnvm file?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, iwlwifi

I have a Dell precision 7560 with an intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210
With fresh Ubuntu 20.04 wifi didn't work, the upgraded kernel wasn't enough and I found on line I need to remove firmware, I removed `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` and it worked.

However, after a while, the file made a comeback (possibly after some relevant update)
So I lose wifi, remove files again, unload and reload kernel drivers (`iwlmvm`,`iwlwifi`) and I'm back in business.

This happened a few times. I lost wifi again (probably a while ago, I've been wired) and needed to fix it again today, and I noticed the file to remove wasn't there.
Today I needed to remove `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode` and reload drivers. And I have my wifi back.

The correct firmware appears to be: `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode`

Is there a more permanent solution, which won't have me semi-randomly losing wifi and then figuring out which files I want to delete? I can script something to delete stuff based on a file pattern but I feel I don't understand well enough what is going on, what these files are, what brings them back, will I always and forever want the file I currently use and not a slightly different name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a bug which is causing this issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13), so each time the package `linux-firmware` gets updated or reinstalled, you have to repeat the process. Although you can hold the package and prevent it from updating, it will **cause more and more issues**. So, you've to repeat the process every time.

If you don't care about anything and want to give it a shot, run the following command to hold the package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-firmware
```

You can unhold it using:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-firmware
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure the cure is better than the disease. The bug seems open, but someone in comments suggested a fix in kernel 5.16 (Which is even newer than what will be in ubuntu 22.04). I guess I will continue with the hack in the meantime.