# WiFi adapter not found on NVIDIA Jetson Orin NX running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, nmcli

My Jetson embedded device has a WLAN SMA-RP Antenna supported by a network controller (Intel AX210) as specified by the manufacturer.

The network controller shown using the command `lspci` is *Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)*. Seems like `lsusb` can also identify this interface as *8087:0032 Intel Corp*.

I do not see a *wlan* or similar interface in my network interfaces using `ifconfig` (I only see *lan1*, *lan2*, *lo*, *rndiso0*, *usb0*). The network manager is not able to find any Wi-Fi device: `sudo nmcli device wifi rescan` returns:
*Error: No Wi-Fi device found*. Trying to connect to any Wi-Fi network produces the same output, and `sudo nmcli device wifi list` and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` both return nothing.

Executing `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` seems like it detects the Wi-Fi modem:

```
[   13.228585] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Adding to iommu group 10
[   13.237621] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   13.317243] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   13.341919] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[   13.360719] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.635397] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   13.816492] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x5a8dfca
[   14.076043] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[   14.082239] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   14.088439] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 0
[   14.107445] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   14.125909] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: retry init count 0
[   14.143089] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   14.568037] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[   14.574611] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   14.580791] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 0
[   14.599730] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   14.618158] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: retry init count 1
[   14.635356] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   15.060048] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[   15.069672] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   15.080880] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 0
[   15.103163] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   15.141228] iwlwifi 0007:01:00.0: retry init count 2
```

From the desktop GUI I am getting a "*No Wi-Fi adapter found, make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on*" in the Wi-Fi settings.

Is there some manual configuration I have to do to set up my Wi-Fi interface?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work when I remove my wifi kernel driver (iwlwifi) .pnvm file (see [Is there any permanent fix for no wifi with iwlwifi other than removing the .pnvm file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390071/is-there-any-permanent-fix-for-no-wifi-with-iwlwifi-other-than-removing-the-pnv)). Converting it to a backup file did the trick:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bck
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have the latest firmware packages. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
```

Reboot and let us see a new version of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: Does not seem to solve it, dmesg output is the same.

Comment: May I please take a look? Please run: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and: `ls -al /lib/firmware | grep ty-a0-gf-a0` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Sure, you can find it here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dRm3T3p2Yq/

Comment: Is this a dual boot with Widows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled